# Get all tableview cells with accessory type checkmark

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to get all the selected values in the tableview.

For Example:

```
// I'm unable to loop through the tableview (myTableView.cells is not valid)
func saveClicked(sender:AnyObject)
{
 let testArray = NSMutableArray()

  for i in myTableView.cells
  {
    if (i.accessorytype = .CheckMark)
    {
      testArray.addObject(i)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Get the values from your datasource instead, the views are not supposed to be responsible for providing data.

Comment: You will need to get this info from the data source as stated above. If you try to iterate thru all the cells in the tableView, you will only receive back data for the rows that are visible at the time since invisible rows are dequeued from memory and cells are reused.

Comment: So however you are populating your tableView, you will need to keep track of the `.Checkmark` status along with that array. Then you simply iterate thru your array for values that have a `.Checkmark` status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified example. Set up your array of items, `myItemsArray` and give it a `isChecked` property that is a `bool`. Then in your `didSelectRow` method, you toggle the `isChecked` value to `true` or `false` accordingly. Then when you want to find which "cells", technically items in `myItemsArray`, have a value of `true` you can iterate thru the array as shown below. let me know if this is unclear please.

```
var myItemsArray = [Items]()
var checkedItemsArray = [Items]()

override func tableView(tableView:UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    if cell.accessoryType == .Checkmark {
        cell.accesoryType == .None
        myItemsArray[indexPath.row].isChecked == false
    } else if cell.accessoryType == .None {
        cell.accesoryType = .Checkmark
        myItemsArray[indexPath.row].isChecked == true
    }
}

  func saveClicked(){
    myItemsArray.removeAll()

    for i in 0...myItemsArray.count-1 {
        if myItemsArray[i].isChecked == true{
            checkedItemsArray.append(myItemsArray[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that your `saveClicked` function is correct; the `i`in the `for` statement should be just the object in the array so the code can be simplified to:`for i in myItemsArray {
        if i.isChecked == true{
            checkedItemsArray.append(i)
        }
    }`. You should also clear the `checkedItemsArray` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Also, in your `tableView::didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, where are you defining or retrieving the `cell` object?

Comment: I just fixed the `for-loop` thanks for catching that! Just forgot the `0...` before `myItemsArray.count-1` . Good catch on clearing the array too. That is always the first bug I catch in my programs unfortunately. And as I said stated, it is a simplified example. The question asker may infer from the example that they will need to define `cell` perhaps with something like `let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)`

Answer (score 1):

1. IT you want default checkmark for tableview cell then Add

cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark

in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" delegate method

2. If you want checkmark on selection of rows then add

override func tableView(tableView:UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    if cell.accessoryType == .Checkmark {
        cell.accesoryType == .None
    } else if cell.accessoryType == .None {
        cell.accesoryType = .Checkmark
    }
}